# Setting up gwtupload with uiBinder

Tags: gwt, file-upload, uibinder, gwtupload

I'm trying to setup the [gwtupload](http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/) widget with uiBinder and I'm having a hard time getting this configured.

I got the code working with the regular `gwt-fileUpload` widget, but I wanted the `gwtupload` because of it's richer functionality.  Here is what I did for the `gwt-fileUpload` widget:

```
    @UiHandler("calculateComplexityButton")
    void onClickCalculateComplexity(ClickEvent e){
        formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
        formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);
        formPanel.setAction(UPLOAD_ACTION_URL);
        String fileName = fileUpload.getFilename();
        fileUpload.setName(fileName);
        formPanel.submit();
    }
```

I'm not seeing how to setup the same thing with `gwtupload`.  I'm seeing this error:

```
HTTP ERROR: 404 NOT_FOUND
RequestURI=/servlet.gupld
```

I don't understand how to map the `gwtupload` widget to my servletPath, because I'm configuring it under uiBinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the servletPath, you must first

1. Set up a custom ui namespace, ie I used "up" below:
2. Define the servletPath in the widget definition itself.

   ```
   <up:MultiUploader type="LABEL" ui:field="uploader" 
     servletPath="/...     /SampleUploadServlet" 
     styleName="{style.myup}" maximumFiles="2" 
     avoidRepeatFiles="true"   validExtensions="xml"/>
   ```